# Is it possible to have numpy generate same random numbers from distribution in different invocations?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two separate files running on same machine but in different instances of vscode. Both files were doing same logical thing implemented in different way but generating different outputs. I debugged both side by side to check the values of various variables at different steps. I realise random numbers generated are different in both of them even though the seed was set in both of them. I quickly checked the behavior in python terminal:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed = 4
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.10854165, -0.42618061,  0.00569403, -0.80871141, -0.3836921 ]])
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.70291615,  0.59154014, -0.83395552,  0.51728728, -0.03152187]])
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[ 0.351498  ,  0.2164184 ,  0.87155382,  0.13872203, -0.30487752]])
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.20548157,  0.32959061, -0.87700352, -0.48807404,  0.78473707]])
```

It seems that setting `np.random.seed` does not guarantee generation of same random numbers in different invocation of `np.random.uniform()`. Is it so? And if yes, then why? And how can can I ensure same random numbers are generated in different invocation?

Comment: Try resetting the seed before each call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got confused about how random seeds work. Each time you set the seed, the random generator restart from the point using that seed.

For example, suppose for seed=4, the random generator is generating this series: X1,X2,X3,.... . Every single time you set the seed to 4, the first element will be X1, and the second always X2. If you desire to get X1 always, all you have to do is to call the rest of the seed, i.e put `np.random.seed = 4` before random generation.

In other words, you can try this modified version of your code, which will give you always the same numbers:

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed = 4
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.10854165, -0.42618061,  0.00569403, -0.80871141, -0.3836921 ]])
>>> np.random.seed = 4
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.10854165, -0.42618061,  0.00569403, -0.80871141, -0.3836921 ]])
>>> np.random.seed = 4
>>> np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,5))
array([[-0.10854165, -0.42618061,  0.00569403, -0.80871141, -0.3836921 ]])
```

Comment: I have two separate py files, I run one in one instance of vscode, a break point hits, I tried `var1` in debug console. Then I run other code in different instance of vscode, break point hits, I prints `var1` in that window. Both `var1` are different in two different windows. Why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you mean you run the same piece of code( at least random generation part) on two different instance machines?

Comment: What version of python you are using? and which version of numpy?

Comment: Python 3.8.6, numpy  1.19.3